# An error occurs in the setting in BigQuery's DataTransferService

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Click on "ttransfer" in BQ's WebUI, enter customerID etc and press "add", the user's selection will appear.

If you press "next" on the next screen, you will return to BQ's webUI and the following error message will be displayed:

> Error when creating new transfer

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there was an OAuth popup that was popup blocked. Please check.
Here are instructions if you are on Chrome:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en